# MKMapview inside collection view cell not visible

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, mapkit

I have created a collection view containing 4 cells. In one of them I would like to display a MapView. This is my collection view cell code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class PestañaUno: UICollectionViewCell, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate
{
    let manager = CLLocationManager()

    override init(frame: CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        Setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    var Mapa: MKMapView =
    {
        var map = MKMapView()
        map.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 400)
        map.mapType = MKMapType.standard
        return map
    }()

    func Setup()
    {
        addSubview(Mapa)
    }
```

And here is when I try to call that collectionviewcell code.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    if indexPath.item == 1
    {
        let myCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PestañaUno", for: indexPath) as! PestañaUno
    }

    return myCell
}
```

Comment: Are you setting collection view cell height and width ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
}
```

Don't forget to implement delegate method.

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return [YOUR ITEM COUNT]
}
```